# what is better to represent news in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

am trying to create a news website where the news should be represented as a picture and small text that when you click on it a new page that represent the whole news will open, so i was thinking of the best way to do that, should i be doing an html table that has a row for images and a row for the text or a list? or maybe it should be in an sql table and i call it with php?

i want something that is easy to add to it when i want to put some new news. i made it as a table but am not really sure that it is the right way to be done. i dont what to delete old news when i want to add new news i just want to show the older news as much as u scroll down the page, here is the code of the table, it simple.

```
<table id="context_table" cellspacing="5" border="2" cellpadding="0"   style="display: inline-block;">
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200" ><img src="paper.gif" alt="paper" height="115" /></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>news discription</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><img src="1920x1920.jpg" alt="film" height="115" /></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>news discription</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>
<tr valign="top" align="right">
<td width="200"><p>pictures</p></td>
<td width="1" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
<td width="600" valign="top" align="left">
<p>Here is the news</p>
<p>blah<br>blah<br>blah</p>

</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i suggest installing a cms.

Comment: yes a cms like [drupal](http://drupal.org) will do ease the stress significantly

Comment: I also recommend using modern semantic HTML5 tags and CSS, rather than turn-of-the-century table-based layout.

Comment: its for a class so i have to do it by coding

Comment: you should consider using `<article></article>` for news items instead of table rows

Comment: then what did they teach you to do? you need to separate out display and storage. just because you display a HTML table, doesn't mean you should store it like that - must would use a db and a template

Comment: Install wordpress and then create a template for this. Then use infinite scroll plugin for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laying out websites with tables has been frowned upon for around 10 years. For tables, it's fine, not but for layouts.

I would markup some news articles like this:

```
<article>
    <a href="/link-to-article/" title="article title">
        <img src="link-to-image" alt="article title">
        <h2>Article title</h2>
        <p>Short description</p>
    </a>
</article>
```

The rest of your question is pretty unclear so would need some more details  explained clearer to be able to help with the rest of what you want.

Comment: forget about the rest of the question its something else ill do it later but let me fist try your way

Comment: want the description and the image to appear in the same line

Comment: it is a gd idea thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to post news to your website, you will need an administration interface, which will be accessed only by you as an admin. There you can post, edit, or delete news. The other one is the user interface, alias your readers, which read the news. First you need to consider the architecture you will use for this. The MVC (Model-View-Controller) is the most widely used architecture for web applications. It separates the view, controller and model from each other, that means, the design and the business logic are indipendent from one another. Here the links to understand MVC concept in depth: 
https://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController

There are different js framework that use MVC concept, Ember, Angular, Backbone etc.

So, you can use php in backend, and js in frontend.

As for the layout, tables are out of date, with some expections, like the e-mail. You will need to use divs for that.

After you read and understand the concept of mvc, you will have a better understadning of what you are gonna do. :)